# How to resolve undefined reference to wxString, when making File for Aqua3d?

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-14.04, wxwidgets

I m trying to install Aqua3d "obinet.engr.uconn.edu/wiki/index.php/Aqua-3D_dev_manual`", for which I need to first make the file provided with the package, When I try to do so by using the command on terminal:

**$ make -f Makefile.txt**

I am getting the following output:

**g++ `wx-config --libs --cxxflags --gl-libs` -lglut -lGLU -lGL -o aqua3d Aqua3D.o ControlPanel.o EnvironmentPanel.o FileChooser.o InformationPanel.o MainFrame.o PlaybackPanel.o PreferenceWindow.o ViewFileHandler.o NodeAttributeDialog.o Event.o AnnotationEvent.o DequeueEvent.o DropEvent.o EnqueueEvent.o HopEvent.o HopSignal.o NodeEvent.o ReceiveEvent.o WorldEvent.o DataManager.o Environment.o EventManager.o Node.o Parser.o vmath.o trackball.o
Aqua3D.o: In function `Aqua3D::OnInit()':
Aqua3D.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to`wxStandardPathsBase::Get()'
Aqua3D.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `wxString::Bef>
.
.
.
Parser.cpp:(.text+0x1e4d): undefined reference to`wxLogError(wchar_t const*, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [aqua3d] Error 1**

Kindly guide me how to resolve this problem?

FYI, I've already installed freeglut3-dev, libwxgtk2.8-dev, libgtk2.0-dev.

Comment: what is you OS and compiler? Are you sure you installed libwxgtk? Did it give you any errors? If you run "wx-config --cxxflags" (no quotes) will there be any output?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS and g++. 
yes I have installed it using sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev

Comment: @Igor yes there is output to the command "wx-config --cxxflags" and it is:      
 
" -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -pthread"

Comment: sorry, it should've been "wx-config --libs". BTW, I don't think there is a --gl-libs option to wx-config. You can use "wx-config --cxxflags --libs,gl" (no quotes).

Comment: @Igor The output for the command "wx-config --cxxflags --gl-libs" is:
         
"-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
-lwx_gtk2u_gl-2.8  "

Comment: yes, the instructions you follow are wrong. Try to supply "wx-config --cxxflags --libs,gl" (no quotes). You do need to link with wxWidgets library and not just with wxGL one.

Comment: sorry, that's an unrecognized option.

Comment: sorry, I was writing from memory. Please try "wx-config --libs gl" (no comma, just space)

Answer (score 0):

---

Aqua3d can be compiled with g++-4.4 : `sudo apt-get install g++-4.4`

Example, edited Makefile https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWC13UXZFZHJ6OUU/view?usp=sharing

---